# Need help recovering from an SQL injection

Tags: mysql, sql

There was a POST value in one of my fields that i accidentally forgot to escape. I found out that my database was compromised.

I changed my code  escaped the values and I am also now using prepared statement, preventing myself from this happening again.

What do after I made the changes?

Do i need to change the table name, change the password on the database??

Can the hacker still access my table?

Comment: It depends on what he did while the database was vulnerable. Did your code use the root username, so it could make arbitrary changes to the database structure?

Comment: I would definitely change the password and also the user name that can access the database.

Comment: I don't think you need to change the password, since there's no way for him to get that with SQL injection. But you should check to see whether he added any new usernames.

Comment: You didn't tell us which programming language you're using, my guess is PHP combined with `mysql_*` commands - am I right ?

Comment: if you can "forget to escape", you're doing it completely wrong.  you should never need to escape anything manually — use placeholders and bound parameters.

Comment: @Barmar no the structure wasn't changed. I was just found out from my customers that sensitive info was compromised...What do you mean if my code used the root username to make changes?.... I am using PHP

Comment: @Barmar Its not the usernames... my table doesn't have username

Comment: I don't mean username in your table, I mean the usernames used to access mysql. Type `SHOW GRANTS` and make sure there are no unexpected entries.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your database immediately, the hacker had already got your database password       in last hacking process, if your database's post is open in your server, the hacker can control your database directly. changing the table name is useless, hacker can use some normal command show your table name if your website have SQL injection 0day. 
   Maybe you should install some security software for your server or use the CDN protect your website.good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What do you mean by changing my database? Should I just rename it?

Comment: You don't need rename it,but I suggest you change your database password.